# How to know where a string in strings.xml is used

Tags: android, android-studio

As a user of Android Studio, I'd like to know where a string in strings.xml is used because I want to remove the strings which aren't in use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: rightclick]
Right click on a string in your strings.xml-> click "Find Usages" to see where it's used.

[image: no usages]

If it's not used anywhere then a little dialog will pop up in the corner saying so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is what I want to know.

Answer (score 4):

Easier way to find unused strings in Strings.xml is to launch an inspection code from top menu of Android Studio (**Analyse/Inspect code**) on whole project.

In the inspection window, go to "**Android Lint/Unused ressources**", there you will find all the unused strings.

It will avoid you to make "find Usages" for lot of strings !